# Saving specific objects from array into new array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an array called teamArray which contain a teamObject with a id, name and shortname. these names is looped into and populated in an tableView. All these cells can be selected and when a cell is selected the indexPath is inserted into a cellSelected array. I would like to save the selected cells id's from the teamArray into a new array. So I guess I need to compare the cellSelected arrays indexPath with the teamArray? How can I do this?

arrays

```
var teamArray = Array<Team>()
var cellSelected = NSMutableArray()
```

didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    if (self.cellSelected.containsObject(indexPath)) {
        self.cellSelected.removeObject(indexPath)
    } else {
        self.cellSelected.addObject(indexPath)


    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

teamObject

```
class Team: NSObject{
    var id: Int!
    var name: NSString!
    var shortname: NSString!

    init(id: Int, name:NSString, shortname: NSString) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.shortname = shortname
    }
}
```

Comment: So what problem are you facing?

Comment: What do you mean by "cells id's"?

Comment: not able to understand your problem.

Comment: I've added my teamObject so you can see. The id's is the id in the database, which i need for some Api calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var teamSelected = [Team]()`

In your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function:

```
let team = self.teamArray[indexPath.row] as Team
var removed = false

for (index, value) in enumerate(self.teamSelected) {
    if (value == team) {
        self.teamSelected.removeAtIndex(index)
        removed = true
    }
}

if (!removed) {
    self.teamSelected.append(team)
}
```

in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function:

```
let team = self.teamArray[indexPath.row] as Team
var removed = false

for (index, value) in enumerate(self.teamSelected) {
    if (value == team) {    
        cell.accessoryView = cell.accessoryCheck
        removed = true
    }
}

if (!removed) {
    cell.accessoryView = cell.accessoryUncheck
}
```

You can then loop through `teamSelected` when you want to access the ID of the selected `Team`'s

EDIT: Changed name of `cellSelected` to `teamSelected`

Comment: Team does not have a member named containsObject

Comment: i still get [(Team)] does not have a member named containsObject

Comment: Okay but now when i press a already selected row it does not remove the selected ? like removeObject

Comment: Updated. I don't have my Mac with me so I'm unable to test any of it.

Comment: Seem to work now. Have made some changes syntax whise and added cellForRowAtindexPath. Please check :)

Answer (score 0):

Your main `teamArray`, which is load in `TableView`

```
var teamArray = ["Kirit Modi","Kirit Modi 1","Kirit Modi 2","Kirit Modi 3","Kirit Modi 4","Kirit Modi 5","Kirit Modi 6","Kirit Modi 7","Kirit Modi 8","Kirit Modi 9"]
```

And `cellSelected`,

```
var cellSelected = : [String] = []
```

In `TableView` delegate `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {

        if contains(cellSelected, Name[indexPath.row])
        {
            cellSelected.removeObject(Name[indexPath.row])
        }
        else{
            cellSelected.append(Name[indexPath.row])
        }
    }
```

Use the below function to remove object from Array.

```
extension Array {
    mutating func removeObject<U: Equatable>(object: U) {
        var index: Int?
        for (idx, objectToCompare) in enumerate(self) {
            if let to = objectToCompare as? U {
                if object == to {
                    index = idx
                }
            }
        }

        if(index != nil) {
            self.removeAtIndex(index!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can simplify your remove function slightly as `mutating func removeValue<U: Equatable>(object: U) { for (idx, objectToCompare) in enumerate(self) { if (objectToCompare as? U) == object { removeAtIndex(idx); return } } }`

Comment: Or avoid the casting if you write it as a free function: `func removeValue<C: RangeReplaceableCollectionType where C.Generator.Element: Equatable>(inout source: C, value: C.Generator.Element) { if let idx = find(source, value) { source.removeAtIndex(idx) } }`